# how to start any project from cmd outside of htdocs or xampp folder?

Tags: php, cmd, xampp, wamp, wampserver

For ex: my xampp htdocs path is

```
D:\xampp\htdocs
```

But i want to run a project in this folder

```
D:\php
```

when xampp is running how can i do that ?

Comment: How are you running your project? Using localhost like `http://localhost/project/` OR using virtual host like `http://project.local/`

Comment: Virtual Hosts are the best solution. See the Dup answer

Answer (score 0):

You just have to edit your Apache  `httpd.conf` file.
Look for `DocumentRoot` and point it to your new folder.
You have to restart Apache for it to work

Answer (score 0):

Make your folder php in D:
then goto xampp folder and rename htdocs to anything you want
and run the following command in cmd

```
mklink /J C:\xampp\htdocs D:\php
```

Output Put Will Be Like This:

```
C:\Users>mklink /J C:\xampp\htdocs D:\php
Junction created for C:\xampp\htdocs <<===>> D:\php
```